Effect of an power plane adjacent to GND in power delivery network(PDN)
I'm trying to understand the effect of a power plane close to GND plane in power delivery network (PDN):

My question is as far as I understand the value of the plane capacitor which is made by the layer stack up is much smaller than the input bulk capacitors and decoupling capacitors, so how this plane capacitor can have an big impact on the power delivery when it comes to high frequency boards? and in principle why this small capacitor can have a impact?

As you say, "small capacitor", "high frequency" -- what's missing?

@Tim Williams is there very small inductance?


and in principle why this small capacitor can have a impact?

It usually won't have an impact, of a coppper plane capacitor that 1 square inch is in the pf range (like a few pf's). Typically this won't have an effect on most power delivery networks, because also the trace will be in the 1-10mΩ range and also a few nH. The LRC resonant point is usually in the GHz range, for most devices, they don't need to worry about this. For high speed processors, maybe, but capacitance will help because it provides storage in the event the load changes. And in allmost all applications, the bulk capacitors have a bigger effect.
But it is very application dependent.
